# Should I leave honest feedback online for a toxic company I previously worked for?

Tags: salary, feedback, glassdoor

About a year ago I started as a "front-end developer" at a local startup. Previously I had worked for my university and newspaper in various departments doing dev work, and had been doing freelance work as well. I had taken a bit of time off from things since then, moving back to my parents home town for personal reasons, and had just been taking it easy with a part-time job.

I feel like I was extremely friendly and jumped through hoops to do what they asked and kept a smile on my face the whole time, attempting to socialize with people older than myself with poor attitudes and superiority complexes. To this day I am still not sure why they let me go, but I am glad that they did. I am wondering if I should post on glassdoor about my experiences, hopefully letting others know about their shady practices, even though they will know exactly who I am? Perhaps it's none of my business at this point, but I feel like I could at least save someone else the trouble or at least let them know what they are getting involved in. Should I leave a review or should I just mind my own business and move on with things?

Comment: not a duplicate of that question, and thanks for editing out my entire message and the downvote

Comment: My personal take is that online feedback is mostly for feedback about the experience of being one of their _customers_, not one of their employees. If you really believe your statement will cause a massive boycott which will cause things to change inside the company... maybe. More likely it will be dismissed as sour grapes.

Comment: @user24102 Actually, the edit was a useful one. You had several paragraphs of useless information, and Garrison was kind enough to invest time in editing your wall of text, and narrowing it down to a consumable nugget of information that can actually be answered.

Comment: @user24102 You are welcome to revert the edit, but it will definitely fall under the "Real Questions have Answers" close reason.  I didn't downvote, not that it matters.

Comment: Were these people in FL? ;)

Comment: Eh, this place was really bad. Went in with open mind looking to have a great experience and I was constantly let down and disrespected by these people who have a notorious history. I guess everyone on here is assuming I'm just ranting and raving and bitter about some personal conflict but there were serious grievances in that work place and I know that they hire people from out of town and state, so I feel bad for someone making the move only to discover the surefire hell they will be getting involved in. Guess I will just leave it be since I am not able to give an unbiased review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should leave a review on a site like glassdoor if you can do so as neutrally as possible and if you feel it will not be a detriment to your further career. What do I mean by that?

"Did not receive health insurance in a timely fashion" is something you should let other's know about. "Run by deceiving man-babies" is not very helpful on the surface.

I mean, let's be honest here, as a prospect I would absolutely want to know both of those but one is inappropriate to a professional review. And that's what you should keep in mind, professionalism. Right now your question comes off as pretty 'ranty'. I think most readers can sympathize but it's not a great review nor is it professional. And, hey, that's cool - sometimes we just gotta rant right? But ranting of this sort is the kind of thing you don't want tied to your reputation because, legitimate or not, it tends to make you look worse than the company in question.

So what can you say? "High stress environment", "High attrition", "poor description of job duties", "slow to get health insurance information"... things like this could be part of a discrete, professional review. Try to subtract personal feelings from it and move away from 'deceiving manbabies' and more into a discussion of general problems you ran into.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I definitely agree to leave the opinionated bits out, I just figured that many users of this site would have dealt with similar situations and wanted to put things into perspective. I think concise points like you stated would probably be best, what I wrote was definitely a bit of a rant.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has an opinion. You are certainly entitled to air yours. Only fools believe everything they read, so if I read your review, I'll keep in mind that it is he POV of one person at a point in time.

I consulted once at a client site that was a political snake pit. While the parent organization was getting plaudits for being a good place to work, the client site was a horror show - That's the the truth for you, where not everything is white, not everything is black but a mosaic of white and black dots.